# Instant flux density calculation of flyback transformer with airgap

Tags: transformer, switch-mode-power-supply, flyback

How to calculate the **instant flux density** of a flyback transformer with airgap? I am trying to understand airgap is enough or not? Does the instant flux density reach saturation value or not? Also, how to calculate \$N_{primary}\$ of the transformer with respect to airgap?

I have these variables: \$L_{primary}\$, \$\ell_{gap}\$, \$I_{primarypeak}\$, \$I_{primaryrms}\$, \$V_{primarymax}\$, \$V_{primaryrms}\$, \$f_{switching}\$, \$A_{effective}\$, \$D_{max}\$

Comment: Max flux density is a material parameter and is not related to gapping. Do you know your primary inductance? If not then read this: [Why is the air gap important in a flyback transformer?](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/659850/20218). Also, look how your text is rendered: Lgap (lgap as you have written it) renders the same first letter shape as Iprimarypeak. Better to use this: \$\ell_{gap}\$ = `\$\ell_{gap}\$`

Comment: There is a misunderstanding here. Maybe I asked the question the wrong way. I am gonna to edit question for Instant Flux Density.

Comment: Be very careful that any edits you make don't disrespect the answer already given. Use latex for expressions and formulas too.

Comment: I think, i have to ask it with another question. It is gonna to be better for the answer :) Also, i will try to use formula style.

Comment: No, you should edit this question.

Comment: OK, i did it. Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144972/discussion-between-burak-and-andy-aka).

Comment: I'm rolling back your question to remove the mention of permeability. Reason: once you have answers that tell you you have something missing you should not arbitrarily amend your question because this invalidates the answers given. I asked you to be careful about this before so, I feel it is necessary to roll-back your question because now you have two answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *How to calculate the instant flux density of a flyback transformer
> with airgap?*

There is a fundamental equation that relates flux density (\$B\$), core permeability (\$\mu\$) and magnetic field strength (\$H\$). That equation is: -

$$B = \mu H$$

You may have seen that relationship expressed as a graph (known as a BH curve): -

[image]

Image from [here](https://www.researchgate.net/figure/Typical-B-H-loop-of-a-ferromagnetic-material-29_fig4_277174604).

The curve also indicates the magnetic hysteresis associated with many magnetic materials. The dotted line is when beginning the plot (no remnant of magnetism in the core).

Note that \$H\$ is the driving force of magnetism. It accounts for current, the number of turns and, the distance of the flux path. So, you need to know the cores magnetic permeability if you are to find flux density.

> *I am trying to understand airgap is enough or not?*

If you know the permeability of the ungapped core and, you know the effective mean length of the core (as per the diagram below) you can calculate the effect of an air-gap: -

[image]

The  mean length is that shown by the dotted green line and is detailed in the data sheet for the core you are considering. Image from [here](https://www.electrical4u.com/magnetic-reluctance/?utm_content=cmp-true).

So, the formula the relates the gapped and ungapped permeabilities is this: -

$$\mu_{gapped} = \dfrac{\mu_{ungapped}}{\frac{\ell_{gap}}{\ell_{mean}}\cdot\mu_{ungapped}+1}$$

And, this tells you the gapped permeability (also called effective permeability). Then you use this new value in the first formula to calculate the gapped value of flux density.

A good choice for peak flux density is around 200 mT for most ferrite materials. Also note that once you have lowered the permeability by introducing a gap, you will probably need to restore the inductance by adding more turns. This increases the H-field as per [my previous answer to you](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/659844/why-is-the-air-gap-important-in-a-flyback-transformer) entitled **Why is the air gap important in a flyback transformer**.

> *how to calculate \$N_{primary}\$ of the transformer with respect to
> airgap?*

The core data sheet will give you a value for \$A_L\$ and, \$A_L\$ multiplied by \$N^2\$ tells you the value of primary inductance. So, if the gap reduces the permeability by (say) ten, then \$A_L\$ also reduces by a factor of ten.

So, you know the current in your coil and, you know how many turns you need (ungapped and gapped) and, you know the mean length of the magnetic core so, you can calculate what value the H-field is. It's just a tiny bit of number crunching to find the peak flux density.

Comment: Along with your answer to the previous question, I examined Ferit Core hysteresis curves. I've seen that the linearity of these curves usually deteriorates after 0.2 Tesla magnetic flux density. In the sample calculations, I observed that the flux was taken as 0.2 T, as you said, so that the core would not be saturated. Also, your answers are very clear, thanks.